# Refresh data in Chart.js when data added in Angular

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, types, chart.js, refresh

I have a form that adds data to the Firestore and from the firestore renders on the Chart.js (line) . However it doesn't update the chart automatically. What can I do to refresh the chart with new data from the firestore collection?
I tried to use  `this.chart.update();`but not working.

this code generates the chart

```
createChart() {    
   this.aaService.getData(this.id).subscribe(
      (aaServ)  => {
        this.data = aaServ;           
      })
    const abc = this.data.map((item) => item.abc); 
    const xyz = this.data.map((item) => item.xyz); 
    this.chart = new Chart('MyChart', {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: abc,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'xyz',
            data: xyzLabels,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        aspectRatio: 2.5,
      },
    });
  }
```

In the service to get data from firestore

```
getData(id:string){
  return this.db 
  .collection('aaCollection')
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(map(docArray => {
    return docArray.map(doc => {
      return {
        abc: doc.payload.doc.data()['abc'],
        xyz: doc.payload.doc.data()['xyz']
      }
      
    }) 
  }
  ))
 }
}
```

In the component when the form is submitted to be stored in Firestore and suppose to display on the chart.

```
 onSubmit(){
    this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params["id"]; 
    let aa: aaModel = {
      ID: this.id, 
      xyz: this.testForm.value.xyz,
      abc: this.testForm.value.abc,     
    } 
    this.aaService.addBodyMetrics(this.Id, aa);
  }
```

In the service to add data

```
addBodyMetrics( id:string, test:testModel){
  this.db.collection('aaCollection')
  .add(test)
  .then(res => {
    console.log('added Successfully');
  })   
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error  ' ,error);
  });
  
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example with code? Show the data, chart configuration; and how you update the chart when data is updated as mentioned.

Comment: I have added some codes. @YongShun

Comment: Let's say the `addBodyMetrics` is observable, you need to subscribe to the observable and call the `createChart` method to fetch the data and generate the chart. Does it work? And in `createChart` method, `getData` returnsan observable, you should move the code lines from `const abc` until the end into the `subscribe()`, thus these code will only run when the observable returned.

Comment: @YongShun , that is another method is service, used to add data from the form to the firestore collection

Comment: Also show the implementation for the `addBodyMetrics` method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore collection `add()` returns a Promise, modify the `addBodyMetrics` to return promise.

```
addBodyMetrics(id:string, test:testModel) {
  return this.db.collection('aaCollection')
    .add(test);
}
```

In `onSubmit` method, provide the success callback to the promise from `this.aaService.addBodyMetrics` by calling the `getChart` method to generate/update the chart.

```
onSubmit(){
  this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params["id"]; 
  let aa: aaModel = {
    ID: this.id, 
    xyz: this.testForm.value.xyz,
    abc: this.testForm.value.abc,     
  } 
  this.aaService.addBodyMetrics(this.Id, aa)
    .then(res => {
      console.log('added Successfully');
      this.createChart();
    })   
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error  ' ,error);
    });
}
```

While in the `createChart` method, the Observable is asynchronous, you should get the value of Observable returned and initialize the chart data and configuration. Hence, you should move the line from `const abc` until the end into the `subscribe` method.

```
createChart() {    
  this.aaService.getData(this.id).subscribe(
    (aaServ)  => {
      this.data = aaServ;     

      const abc = this.data.map((item) => item.abc); 
      const xyz = this.data.map((item) => item.xyz); 

      if (this.chart)
        this.chart.destroy();

      this.chart = new Chart('MyChart', {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: abc,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'xyz',
              data: xyzLabels,
              backgroundColor: 'red',
            },
          ],
        },
        options: {
          aspectRatio: 2.5,
        },
    });
  });      
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error when submitting the form : Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '1' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'MyChart' can be reused.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that, had edited my answer. Make sure you need to destroy the chart if the chart is rendered.